# Azure DevOps: Run step after pipeline failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Sometimes our builds fail. If that happens, then the workspace is not cleaned. New builds just create new workspaces, which eats up all HDD space.

Is there a way to clean the workspace after the build has failed?

Right now I have a clean-up step with a condition `succeedOrFailed()`, but it works only if the build was cancelled manually. If the build has failed due to a lack of HDD space or because of the timeout -- the clean-up step is not run.

I don't actually need to clean up. If the TFS-agent would just reuse old workspace directories it would have been a fine solution since I have `clean:all` in my `YAML`. But for some reason it prefers to create new ones.

I guess I can run `rm -rf` in `cron`, but then I would need to know when nobody uses the build system.

Comment: i think if you have a HDD space issue, nothing will work anyway ?

Comment: Why? One build cannot take the whole HDD. Only when several builds in a row failed to clean up under themselves we have an issue. @danielorn's suggestion shall work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the condition as `always()`. It will run the cleanup regardless of whether the pipeline failed/succeded or was canceled. This ways the workspace will always clean, also after successful builds, minimizing the risk of getting out of space on the agent

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> Even if a previous dependency has failed, unless the run was canceled.
> Use succeededOrFailed() in the YAML for this condition.
>
> **Even if a previous dependency has failed, even if the run was
> canceled. Use always() in the YAML for this condition.**
>
> Only when a previous dependency has failed. Use failed() in the YAML
> for this condition.

Comment: Thank you. I've emulated 100% HDD utilization to make the build fail and the clean up process happened!